# TF1 code does not work with TF2, could someone convert this TF1 code

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, mnist

I am new to deep learning just installed tensorflow but the tutorial I was following was using TensorFlow 1 and that throws error on my system, can someone convert this code from TensorFlow 1 to TensorFlow 2

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for epoch in range(hm_epochs) :
        epoch_loss = 0
        for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)):
            epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
            epoch_loss += c
        print('Epoch ', epoch, ' completed out of ', hm_epochs, ' loss: ',epoch_loss)
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
    print('Accuracy: ',accuracy.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.lables}))
```

Comment: I think it is better if you follow a tutorial that uses TensorFlow 2.0, it does not make much sense to translate tutorials

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple set of commands to do the trick. Follow along:

**Step 1:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

**output:**

```
2.2.0
```

**Step 2:**

```
git clone --branch r1.13.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/tensorflow/models
```

**output:**

```
Cloning into 'models'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2927, done.[K
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2927/2927), done.[K
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2449/2449), done.[K
remote: Total 2927 (delta 509), reused 2035 (delta 403), pack-reused 0[K
Receiving objects: 100% (2927/2927), 369.04 MiB | 12.36 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (509/509), done.
Checking out files: 100% (2768/2768), done.
```

**Step 3:** Read the help

```
tf_upgrade_v2 -h
```

**output:**

```
usage: tf_upgrade_v2 [-h] [--infile INPUT_FILE] [--outfile OUTPUT_FILE]
                     [--intree INPUT_TREE] [--outtree OUTPUT_TREE]
                     [--copyotherfiles COPY_OTHER_FILES] [--inplace]
                     [--no_import_rename] [--reportfile REPORT_FILENAME]
                     [--mode {DEFAULT,SAFETY}] [--print_all]

Convert a TensorFlow Python file from 1.x to 2.0

Simple usage:
  tf_upgrade_v2.py --infile foo.py --outfile bar.py
  tf_upgrade_v2.py --infile foo.ipynb --outfile bar.ipynb
  tf_upgrade_v2.py --intree ~/code/old --outtree ~/code/new

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --infile INPUT_FILE   If converting a single file, the name of the file to
                        convert
  --outfile OUTPUT_FILE
                        If converting a single file, the output filename.
  --intree INPUT_TREE   If converting a whole tree of files, the directory to
                        read from (relative or absolute).
  --outtree OUTPUT_TREE
                        If converting a whole tree of files, the output
                        directory (relative or absolute).
  --copyotherfiles COPY_OTHER_FILES
                        If converting a whole tree of files, whether to copy
                        the other files.
  --inplace             If converting a set of files, whether to allow the
                        conversion to be performed on the input files.
  --no_import_rename    Not to rename import to compact.v2 explicitly.
  --reportfile REPORT_FILENAME
                        The name of the file where the report log is
                        stored.(default: report.txt)
  --mode {DEFAULT,SAFETY}
                        Upgrade script mode. Supported modes: DEFAULT: Perform
                        only straightforward conversions to upgrade to 2.0. In
                        more difficult cases, switch to use compat.v1. SAFETY:
                        Keep 1.* code intact and import compat.v1 module.
  --print_all           Print full log to stdout instead of just printing
                        errors
```

**Step 4:** Run the following in the terminal (This is for converting a single file)

```
!tf_upgrade_v2 \
  --infile models/samples/cookbook/regression/custom_regression.py \
  --outfile /tmp/custom_regression_v2.py
```

**output:**

```
INFO line 38:8: Renamed 'tf.feature_column.input_layer' to 'tf.compat.v1.feature_column.input_layer'
INFO line 43:10: Renamed 'tf.layers.dense' to 'tf.compat.v1.layers.dense'
INFO line 46:17: Renamed 'tf.layers.dense' to 'tf.compat.v1.layers.dense'
INFO line 57:17: tf.losses.mean_squared_error requires manual check. tf.losses have been replaced with object oriented versions in TF 2.0 and after. The loss function calls have been converted to compat.v1 for backward compatibility. Please update these calls to the TF 2.0 versions.
INFO line 57:17: Renamed 'tf.losses.mean_squared_error' to 'tf.compat.v1.losses.mean_squared_error'
INFO line 61:15: Added keywords to args of function 'tf.shape'
INFO line 62:15: Changed tf.to_float call to tf.cast(..., dtype=tf.float32).
INFO line 65:40: Renamed 'tf.train.AdamOptimizer' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer'
INFO line 68:39: Renamed 'tf.train.get_global_step' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step'
INFO line 83:9: tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error requires manual check. tf.metrics have been replaced with object oriented versions in TF 2.0 and after. The metric function calls have been converted to compat.v1 for backward compatibility. Please update these calls to the TF 2.0 versions.
INFO line 83:9: Renamed 'tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error' to 'tf.compat.v1.metrics.root_mean_squared_error'
INFO line 142:23: Renamed 'tf.train.AdamOptimizer' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer'
INFO line 162:2: Renamed 'tf.logging.set_verbosity' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity'
INFO line 162:27: Renamed 'tf.logging.INFO' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO'
INFO line 163:2: Renamed 'tf.app.run' to 'tf.compat.v1.app.run'
TensorFlow 2.0 Upgrade Script
-----------------------------
Converted 1 files
Detected 0 issues that require attention
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Make sure to read the detailed log 'report.txt'
```

**Step 5:** For converting the whole directory

```
!tf_upgrade_v2 \
    --intree models/samples/cookbook/regression/
    --outtree regression_v2/
    --reportfile tree_report.txt
```

**output:**

```
INFO line 72:10: tf.estimator.DNNRegressor: Default value of loss_reduction has been changed to SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE; inserting old default value tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM.

INFO line 96:2: Renamed 'tf.logging.set_verbosity' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity'
INFO line 96:27: Renamed 'tf.logging.INFO' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO'
INFO line 97:2: Renamed 'tf.app.run' to 'tf.compat.v1.app.run'
INFO line 38:8: Renamed 'tf.feature_column.input_layer' to 'tf.compat.v1.feature_column.input_layer'
INFO line 43:10: Renamed 'tf.layers.dense' to 'tf.compat.v1.layers.dense'
INFO line 46:17: Renamed 'tf.layers.dense' to 'tf.compat.v1.layers.dense'
INFO line 57:17: tf.losses.mean_squared_error requires manual check. tf.losses have been replaced with object oriented versions in TF 2.0 and after. The loss function calls have been converted to compat.v1 for backward compatibility. Please update these calls to the TF 2.0 versions.
INFO line 57:17: Renamed 'tf.losses.mean_squared_error' to 'tf.compat.v1.losses.mean_squared_error'
INFO line 61:15: Added keywords to args of function 'tf.shape'
INFO line 62:15: Changed tf.to_float call to tf.cast(..., dtype=tf.float32).
INFO line 65:40: Renamed 'tf.train.AdamOptimizer' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer'
INFO line 68:39: Renamed 'tf.train.get_global_step' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step'
INFO line 83:9: tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error requires manual check. tf.metrics have been replaced with object oriented versions in TF 2.0 and after. The metric function calls have been converted to compat.v1 for backward compatibility. Please update these calls to the TF 2.0 versions.
INFO line 83:9: Renamed 'tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error' to 'tf.compat.v1.metrics.root_mean_squared_error'
INFO line 142:23: Renamed 'tf.train.AdamOptimizer' to 'tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer'
INFO line 162:2: Renamed 'tf.logging.set_verbosity' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity'
INFO line 162:27: Renamed 'tf.logging.INFO' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO'
INFO line 163:2: Renamed 'tf.app.run' to 'tf.compat.v1.app.run'
INFO line 82:10: tf.estimator.LinearRegressor: Default value of loss_reduction has been changed to SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE; inserting old default value tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM.

INFO line 105:2: Renamed 'tf.logging.set_verbosity' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity'
INFO line 105:27: Renamed 'tf.logging.INFO' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO'
INFO line 106:2: Renamed 'tf.app.run' to 'tf.compat.v1.app.run'
INFO line 58:10: tf.estimator.LinearRegressor: Default value of loss_reduction has been changed to SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE; inserting old default value tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM.

INFO line 101:2: Renamed 'tf.logging.set_verbosity' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity'
INFO line 101:27: Renamed 'tf.logging.INFO' to 'tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO'
INFO line 102:2: Renamed 'tf.app.run' to 'tf.compat.v1.app.run'
WARNING line 125:15: Changing dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() to tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset). Please check this transformation.

INFO line 40:7: Renamed 'tf.test.mock' to 'tf.compat.v1.test.mock'
TensorFlow 2.0 Upgrade Script
-----------------------------
Converted 7 files
Detected 1 issues that require attention
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File: models/samples/cookbook/regression/automobile_data.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
models/samples/cookbook/regression/automobile_data.py:125:15: WARNING: Changing dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() to tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset). Please check this transformation.
Make sure to read the detailed log 'tree_report.txt'
```

**Step 6:** Add this to the code

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

**Step 7:** If you are using nn, then replace `tf.nn.rnn_cell.xyz` with

```
tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.xyz
```

**You’re good to go after this.**

Answer (score 0):

What problem you are having exactly? Is it the code or the mnist dataset? 
I also started learning TF recently and it seems to me that there are more tutorials for TF1 than for TF2, so after some struggle with TF2 I eventually uninstalled it and installed TF1.

Apart from the compatibility issues e.g. tf.Session() doesn't exist in TF2, I also had a problem with mnist dataset itself. I couldn't access its elements in the same way as my TF1 tutorial.

If your problem is just the compatibility, you can use something like

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

and use the TF1-specific functions with "compat.v1" as e.g.

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
```